# How to combine the outcome of query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table about metro card of station enter and record `record(cid, enter_sid, exit_sid)`
I want to get the total number of enter and out each station.
For example,

`cid    enter_sid    exit_sid
   1         1             2
   1         1             2
   1         2             3
   2         2             1`

I want to get

```
sid   count(*)
1         3
2         4
3         1
```

I don't know how to combine `select cid, count(*) from record group by enter_sid` and `select cid, count(*) from record group by exit_sid`

cid means id of card.
For the first row of my expected outcome, 1 is for the id of station, 3 is for sid 1 existing 2 times in enter_sid and 1 time in exit_sid.

Comment: What exactly is your `cid` column?

Comment: how does your expected outcome match up with the columns values and or count?

Comment: id of card, which don't have much meaning in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the trick to this is your enter and exit sid are the first column so you have to union those two together to get the correct combination... from there its a simple sum of the count.

```
SELECT sid, cid, SUM(counting) FROM
(
  SELECT cid, enter_sid as sid, COUNT(*) as counting FROM record GROUP BY enter_sid
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cid, exit_sid as sid, COUNT(*) as counting FROM record GROUP BY exit_sid
)t
GROUP BY sid
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fac1/1)